# AngularJs: Run function when any element in section is blurred

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created the following directive:

```
.directive('onSectionBlur', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.focusout(function (event) {
                if (!jQuery.contains($element[0], event.relatedTarget)) {
                    $scope.$apply($parse($attrs.onSectionBlur)($scope));
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

My goal here is if a user tabs out of a section of a form (or clicks elsewhere), I want to display a read-only version of that data:  http://jsfiddle.net/uZBXw/3/

So this works from what I can tell, but I feel like I was just mashing buttons on this line:

```
$scope.$apply($parse($attrs.onSectionBlur)($scope));
```

Is this the correct way to run code and wire it into the angular lifecycle?

Comment: you should pass function to $apply, you execute a function and pass result value there, you should wrap your $parse in anynymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use an isolated scope with an attribute marked with `&`. This will give you access to a function that will run on the *parent scope* and is the exact use case of what you're trying to do.

```
app.directive('onSectionBlur', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'notify': '&onSectionBlur' // reuse the directive name for easier handling
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.on('focusout', function (evt) {
        if (!angular.element.contains(element[0], evt.relatedTarget)) {
          scope.$apply(scope.notify); // let $apply call the notify-callback
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/diwetaje/1/

---

from the [Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> **Best Practice**: use `&attr` in the scope option when you want your directive to expose an API for binding to behaviors.

Comment: Works great!  Any reason the code was moved from controller to link?

Comment: @John Well there is another best-practice note in the developer guide: *Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.*

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with clicking on various items in the section (i.e. checkbox labels), so if anyone else runs across this issue I've added a potential enhancement to Yoshi's version:

```
.directive('onSectionBlur', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'notify': '&onSectionBlur'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var hasFocus = false;

            element.on('focusin', function (evt) {
                hasFocus = true;
            });

            $document.on('click focusin', function (evt) {
                if (hasFocus && !angular.element.contains(element[0], evt.target)) {
                    hasFocus = false;
                    scope.$apply(scope.notify);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT:  Here's the butchered up version I ended up with, that takes into account buttons that weren't clickable (if they were outside the section and below it) as well as not firing the event if the user has a modal window open:

```
    link: function (scope, element) {
        var hasFocus = false;
        var lostFocus = function () {
            hasFocus = false;
            scope.$apply(scope.notify);
        };

        element.on('focusin', function (evt) {
            hasFocus = true;
        });
        element.on('keydown', function (evt) {
            if (hasFocus && evt.keyCode == 9) {
                //Using timeout to give the browser time to process what it should have been doing (i.e. focusing next item)
                if (evt.shiftKey && element.find(':focusable:first').is(evt.target)) {
                    $timeout(lostFocus);
                } else if (element.find(':focusable:last').is(evt.target)) {
                    $timeout(lostFocus);
                }
            }
        });

        var docHandler = function (evt) {
            //If the click came from inside of a modal window, ignore it
            if (angular.element(evt.target).closest('.modal').length == 0) {
                if (hasFocus && !angular.element.contains(element[0], evt.target)) {
                    lostFocus();
                }
            }
        };

        $document.on('click', docHandler);
        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            $document.off('click', docHandler);
        });
    }
```